# Trouble Installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 on Gateway GT5404

Tags: boot, 14.04, usb, gateway

I have a Gatway GT5404 (desktop) with 2GB's of ram and a newer HDD, and a refresh of windows 7 ultimate. Ive tried installing Ubuntu via USB by extracting the iso files into the USB, Extracting the ISO file and then copying it to USB, even using IMGBurner to write a bootable IMG to the USB. No matter what i try, after reboot it'll try and boot via USB and it says "BOOTMNGR is missing." Could it be my windows install? This system came with vista and I wasnt cool with that so I upgraded it to windows 7. I dont have any DVD's large enough to write Ubuntu onto and would like to focus on USB. I use the desktop as an everyday basic system so if I have to completely format my HDD and install ubuntu on it as a last resort, I will.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an application like UNetbootin.

It can create a bootable Live USB drive.

It loads distributions either by downloading a ISO (CD image) files for you, or by using an ISO file you've already downloaded.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) successfully in the past. If that doesn't work, also try [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) as suggested in the [Ubuntu help article](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).